# Let $D,m$ be relatively prime integers with $m$ odd. Then $D \equiv 0,1 \pmod 4$ and $D \equiv b^2 \pmod m$ implies that $D \equiv b^2 \pmod{4m}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

This is from a proof in David A. Cox's Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$:

> **Lemma 2.5** *Let $D\equiv 0,1 \bmod 4$ be an integer and $m$ be an odd integer relatively prime to $D$.  Then $m$ is properly represented by a primitive form of discriminant $D$ if and only if $D$ is a quadratic residue modulo $m$.*

> *Proof:* If $f(x,y)$ properly represents $m$ then by Lemma 2.3, we may assume $f(x,y) = mx^2 + bxy + cy^2$. Thus $D=b^2-4mc$, and $D\equiv b^2 \bmod m$ follows immediately.

> $\;\;\;\;$ Conversely, suppose that $D\equiv b^2 \bmod m$.  Since $m$ is odd, we can assume that $D$ and $b$ have the same parity (replace $b$ by $b+m$ if necessary), and then $D\equiv 0,1 \bmod 4$ implies that $D\equiv b^2 \bmod 4m$. $[\ldots]$

I cannot see how, in the third paragraph,  $D \equiv b^2 \pmod{4m}$ follows. I tried doing examples to get an intuition for why it holds, but I cannot figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I like that book.  You can probably work it out yourself by thinking about the need to have $b$ replaced by $b+m$ should $D,b$ not have the same parity.  The missing step is that $D\equiv b^2 \bmod 4$.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey key information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is an explanation of why this is bad lractice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: I edited the post to replace the image with typeset math notation.  For a brief MathJax introduction see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and follow its links for further topics.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that.

Comment: Why wouldnt $D=85$ and $m=49$ be a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $b^2\equiv 0~({\rm mod~}4)$ if $b$ is even, and $b^2\equiv 1~({\rm mod~}4)$ if $b$ is odd. Since $D$ and $b$ can be made of the same parity, the assumption on $D$ shows that $D\equiv b^2~({\rm mod ~}4).$

To complete the result that $D\equiv b^2~({\rm mod~}4m),$ just note that $m$ is odd, so $D\equiv b^2~({\rm mod~}m)$ and $D\equiv b^2~({\rm mod~}4)$ together give the result.

Comment: (I didn't downvote) Could you give some more detail for the $b$ is odd case? I can see how $b^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$ follows, but can't see how to then get $D \equiv b^2 \mod 4m$. I assume it uses $gcd(m,4)=1$, but I cannot see how. As much detail as you can give is appreciated.

Comment: It follows from division algorithm or unique factorization theorem. Note that you have $4|(D-b^2)$ and $m|(D-b^2)$ but $\gcd(4,m)=1$.

Comment: Hence it follows that $4m|(D-b^2)$.

Comment: I'm still not seeing why $b$ must be odd though. What about $D=85$, $m=49$. Then $D \equiv_{49} 36$ but $D \equiv_{4×49} 36+85$

Comment: @Mike I don’t understand your question. $b$ is not assumed to be odd.

Comment: But $b$ must be odd for $4$ to divide $D-b^2$.

Comment: In that case, that is used to show that $D$ is a quadratic residue mod $4m$. For example in your example, one has $D\equiv (6+49)^2~({\rm mod~}4\times 49).$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this holds unless we assume $b$ is odd. Let $D=81$ and $m=45$. Then $(D \pmod {45}) =36=6^2$ but $(D \pmod {4×45})=81=36+49$ $=36+m$.

If on the other hand $D \pmod m$ is an *odd* square $b^2$, then because both $D$ and $m$ are odd, it follows that the equation $D=b^2+km$ must hold for an integer $k$ that must be *even*. But the fact that $D \pmod 4 = b^2 \pmod 4$ implies that $km$ must in fact be a multiple of $4$, which implies $k$ must be a multiple of $4$. Thus $D=b^2+km$ for some $k$ which is a multiple of $4$, which gives $D = b^2+c(4m)$, where $c$ is the integer such that $k=4c$. In particular, as $D=c(4m)$ for some integral $c$, it follows that $D \pmod{4m} = b^2$ as well.

Comment: Are you referring to the question and proof appearing in the body?  If $D$ and $b$ don't have the same parity, then you replace $b$ with $b+m$, forcing $D$ and $b$ to have the same parity.